# Evaluating the Gaussian integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx $ with the substitution $x=\frac{1}{t}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I got $dx=-t^{-2}dt$, giving me

$$
\int_{0}^{1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2t^{2}}}t^{-2}dt
$$

I can already tell that the above equation can't be right since it is negative everywhere. It actually evaluates to 1 minus the actual answer.

What am I doing wrong and what would be the correct limits?

EDIT:
What if my integral were

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}e^{x}dx
$$

Then performing the substitution $x=\frac{1}{t}$ would give me

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}-e^\frac{1}{t}t^{-2}dt
$$

Which can't be right because the number in the integral is always negative. Is this substitution not correct?

Comment: Your change of variables has a singularity when $x=0$.

Comment: $x=1/t$ and $-\infty\lt x\lt1$ does not yield $0\lt t\lt1$.

Comment: Why can't I set the lower limit to be $a$ and let $a\rightarrow -\infty$?

Comment: Good idea. Try to see what happens with $-42\lt x\lt1$ when $x=1/t$. Where will be $t$?

Comment: $-\frac{1}{42}<t<1$ right? Sorry if something is completely flying over my head right now.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{1} f(x) dx = \left[\int_{-\infty}^{0-} + \int_{0+}^{1}\right] f(x) dx = \left[\int_{0}^{-\infty} + \int_{\infty}^{1}\right] f(\frac{1}{t}) (-\frac{dt}{t^2} )$

Comment: No, not right. Examples: if $x=\pm1/2$ (both in $(-42,1)$) then $t=\pm2$ (none of these in $(-1/42,1)$).

Comment: I don't see why anyone would want to "evaluate" this non-elementary integral using the substitution $x:={1\over t}$.